# Progresswheel type thing in canvas not stopping at the desired percentage. Gettin undefined for value

Tags: javascript, canvas

just a quick one today (i hope)

The code below generates a random number between 0-28, then it passes that number to my progressbar function. The progress bar function is supposed to stop when it reaches the number generated but it is not, insted i am getting undefined for my value. Anyone know why? I'm looking but I just can't see what the issue is. Any light that you could shed on  it would be appreciated

```
 function getRandInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); // to get the element
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); //to return drawing context on canvas
    var al=0; // use it for Amount loaded
    var start=4.72; //From where to start position of progress;
    var cw=context.canvas.width/2; //to get x cordinate;
    var ch=context.canvas.height/2; // to get y coordinate;

    //here width and height is divided by two so to get our progressbar in middle.

    var diff; //to load progress bar Slowly

    function progressBar(numGiven) {
        var perc = ((numGiven / 28) * 100);
        diff = (al / 100) * Math.PI * 2;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(cw, ch, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = '#FFF';
        context.fill();
        context.strokeStyle = '#e7f2ba';
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.strokeStyle = '#b3cf3c';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.lineWidth = 15;
        context.font = '10pt Verdana';
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(cw, ch, 50, start, diff + start, false);
        context.stroke();
        // old value to show percent al + '%'
        context.fillText(numGiven + "/ 28", cw + 2, ch + 6);
        if (al >= perc) {
            clearTimeout(bar);
        }

        al++;
    }

    var bar = setInterval(progressBar, 50);

    //check for Navigation Timing API support
    if (window.performance) {
        alert("window.performance works fine on this browser");
    }
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        alert("This page is reloaded");            
        progressBar(getRandInt(0, 28))
    } else {
        alert("This page is not reloaded");
        progressBar(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>By quickly looking over your code I noticed that you use setInterval to periodically update your progress bar, but you clear it with clearTimeout. You should use clearInterval instead. Let me know it that's the mistake.</del>

**Edit**: Above thing I noticed was wrong.

Your interval calls your progressBar function without parameters, therefore numGiven is undefined. In order to give the number to your function you should remove your setInterval and replace the condition inside your progressBar function with this:

```
if (al < perc) {
    setTimeout(function(){ progressBar(numGiven) }, 50);
}
```

If you want to use an interval instead, you have to set numGiven as global variable and access it directly in your progressBar function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: @M_Griffiths I took another look at your code and found the problem.